# How many 3 digit integers...?

Tags: integers

How many different 3-digit integers have the product of their digits equal to 4!? What is the largest of these integers?

I know 4! Is 24 but still confusing to do this. How do I find the largest let alone how many?

Comment: First thing: How many ways are there to factor 24?  How many of those are three single digit integer.  How many ways are there to arrange those factors into three digit numbers.

Comment: Finding the largest is easier then counting them.  What is the largest single digit factor of $24$.  That will be the first digit.  If you factor what is left what is the largest single digit factor of that.  That will be the second digit.

Answer (score 3):

How many ways can you write $24$ as a product of one digit whole numbers?

$24 = 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 6$ is one way, giving you the numbers $146$, $164$, $416$, $461$, $614$, and $641$.

Try to find the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

$4! = 24$ how many ways are there to factor $24$ into three factors.

There's $1*1*24$

$1*2*12$

$1*3*8$

.....  etc.

How many of those have only single digit factors?

There's

$1*3*8$

$1*4*6$

$2*2*6$

... etc.

How many ways are there to arrange $1,3,8$ into different orders?  There's $138, 183, 318, ...$.  How many?

Do that for all the other ways of factoring.  How many are there?  And what is the largest one?

Hint: if $8$ is the largest single digit factor than doesn't it make sense that the largest such three digit number would be in the $8$ hundreds.

Now, that was the hard way.  Were there any handy mathematical observations you might have used to make this easier?  Would knowing that $24 = 2^3*3$ is the unique prime factorization of $24$ have helped you find the ways to find three term factorizations?  Would knowing there are $k!$ ways to arrange $k$ objects have helped?  What if some of the objects were indistinguishable?

Answer (score 0):

$xyz= 2^3 .3 $

powers of $2$ can be divided among $x,y,z$  in

$^{3+(3-1)} \ C _{3-1}= 10 $ ways

and power of  $3$ can be divided into $^{1+(3-1)} \ C _{3-1}= 3 $ ways

thus giving total $10\times 3 =30 $ways

but here we also counted arrangements like $2 \times 1\times 12 $  and $1\times 1\times 24$ which violates 3 digit number policy  so, by  subtracting these i.e, $\left(3! + \dfrac{3!}{2!}\right)=9  $ ways

we get

total number of $3$ digit numbers having product $4 != (30-9)=21  $

and out of all such $3$ digit numbers largest is  $8 3 1$